# PowerShell remoting using Kerberos

Tags: powershell, remote, authentication, kerberos

I need to ditch basic authentication and start using another way to execute my powershell scripts.
The problem is I cannot make it work. I am noob at this, so I don't have clear idea where to go next.

What I usually did is for example:

```
enter-pssession servernameA
```

It throws an error now:

```
Connecting to remote server servernameA failed with the following error message : The client cannot c
onnect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accept
ing requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonl
y IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and co
nfigure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (servernameA:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken
```

First thing I ensured is that SPN is created, and there it is seems to be fine:

```
setspn -l servernameA
WSMAN/servernameA
WSMAN/servernameA.mydomain
```

Then I ran winrm quickconfig as suggested by error message:

```
winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Am I missing something obvious here or is it notorious for giving user problems?

```
Get-WSManInstance winrm/config/listener -Enumerate
    cfg                   : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/listener
xsi                   : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
lang                  : en-US
Address               : *
Transport             : HTTP
Port                  : 5985
Hostname              :
Enabled               : true
URLPrefix             : wsman
CertificateThumbprint :
ListeningOn           : {xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 127.0.0.1, ::1}
```

Comment: It really isn't; rather, it usually just works _by default._ What OS and which PowerShell version are you using on both the client and the server? What kind of 'basic' authentication have you been using in the past, and what configuration have you done to enable it? Do you have Kerberos tickets on the client? (That is, according to `klist` do you have a TGT in general? and according to Wireshark/tcpdump is the client at least trying to obtain a ticket for WSMAN/serverA specifically?)

Comment: My client: PSVersion: 5.1.14393.5066, OS: 10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
servernameA: PS Version: 5.1.14393.5066, OS 10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

I do not know the details, because I was done by admin team at company I work for (yes, it would make sense to ask them first, but they are even more useless than I am). I just support monitoring tool.
Basically what they said is WinRM basic authentication was disabled and we need to use different authentication type. Here's what I got

winrm get winrm/config/service/auth
Auth
    Basic = false
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true

Comment: klist returned only few values for my RDP connection, which were generated when I remoted to run command locally

Comment: Did klist return a `krbtgt/YOUR.REALM @ YOUR.REALM` item specifically?

Comment: Yes, row
#0>     Client: username @ mydomain.net Server: krbtgt/mydomain.net @ mydomain.net

Comment: After `enter-pssession servernameA`, does an item for `WSMAN/servernameA` appear? Does adding `-Authentication Kerberos` or `-Authentication Negotiate` improve things?

Comment: I do not see WSMAN/servernameA after trying to connect. 

I did stumble upon another server to which I can remote just fine, using Kerberos or Negotiatie. 
From what I can see it has same settings, so it's quite confusing.

Comment: The full syntax is `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName servernameA`.

Comment: I found there two errors in Event Log of Remote Management  `WSMan operation CreateShell failed, error code 2150858770`         
`Re-sending the request as a result of ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT, using next proxy`

Comment: @gluetornado If your remote server is an IIS web server, or provides HTTP/HTTPS hosting, [see if this is relevant](https://www.grimadmin.com/article.php/winrm-connection-issues-http-inc-list)

Comment: @gluetornado On the server you are trying to remotely connect, run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force;` and then try to run your remote command again. If that doesn't do it, try `Enable-PSRemoting -Force -SkipNetworkProfileCheck;` and then see if it allows connection.